# Code management on Amazon EC2 with SVN and IDE

Tags: amazon-ec2, svn, netbeans

I was looking for a solution to a generic issue most developers might be facing.

I have a PHP Application running locally on WAMP which I wish to deploy to Amazon AWS. I currently manage version control via SVN at assembla.

Now, I wish to send the code to EC2 but alongside also keep developing and committing new code into the application - but am unable to figure our how.

I can understand I need to install SVN at EC2 but is it advisable to checkout the www directory or can it even be checked out and updated live?

Somewhere I read that I can create a repository anywhere and once I commit code - the production code in the www directory can be updated somehow.

Can anyone give tips here? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Found it. For anyone landing here searching for this information - below is what I finally do.

I started up an application in the Elastic Beanstalk. It can be configured with Git and code can be pushed to it from my computer.

I create 2 environments and regularly switch and between them for seamless transition.

More Information here - http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/03/20/php-and-git-deployment-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Cheers!